# How to replace preceding values with zeros in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Table is like:-

```
  ID    AMOUNT    PAID  
   1       500     100
   1       500      50
   1       500     200 
   2      1000     300
   3       800     500
```

--I want to print ID 1 values should be zeros except first value like:-

```
  ID    AMOUNT    PAID 
   1       500     100
   1         0      50
   1         0     200 
   2      1000     300
   3       800     500
```

--Instead of repeating values have to be replaced with zeros

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first value" unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

This is better done at the application layer.  Assuming you have an ordering column, you *can* do it in SQL:

```
select id,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by ??) = 1
             then amount
             else 0
        end) as amount,
       paid
from t
order by id, ??;
```

The `??` represents the column used for ordering.